# API Platform : custom filter is not working

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I created a custom filter in order to check if a table attribute is not "Brouillon" but when I call it in my Entity, nothing happens.

Here are my files:

NotCaracteristiqueFilter.php:

```
<?php
// api/src/Filter/RegexpFilter.php

namespace App\Filter;

use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Type;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\BooleanFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;

final class NotCaracteristiqueFilter extends BooleanFilter
{
    public function apply(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, ?string $operationName = null, array $context = [])    {

            $value = $this->extractProperties([$this->getProperties()], $queryBuilder);

            if ($value === true) {
                $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
                $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.etuCaracteristique != :brouillon', $rootAlias));
                $queryBuilder->setParameter('brouillon', 'Brouillon');
            }

    }

}
```

service.yaml :

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/EventListener/'

    App\Filter\NotCaracteristiqueFilter:
        
    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Etude.php (my entity):

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Filter\NotCaracteristiqueFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;

/**
 * Etude
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *      itemOperations={
 *      "get"={
 *          "normalization_context" ={"groups"= {"client", "test", "sponsor", "commercial", "user", "projet"}}
 * 
 *      }, 
 *      "patch","delete"},
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context" ={"groups"= {"client", "test", "sponsor", "commercial", "user", "projet"}}
 *          }
 *      },
 *     filters={NotCaracteristiqueFilter::class}
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"etuNum": "start", "etuCaracteristique" : "partial", "etuDe.paraphe" : "partial", "etuSponsor.spoIntitule" : "partial","etuCommercial.comNom": "partial","etuStudyManager.paraphe":"partial","etuStatus":"partial"})}) 
 * @ORM\Table(name="etude", indexes= {@ORM\Index(name="Etu_Commerical", columns={"Etu_Commercial"}), @ORM\Index(name="Etu_Test", columns={"Etu_Test"}), @ORM\Index(name="Etu_client", columns={"Etu_Cli"}), @ORM\Index(name="Etu_Sponsor", columns={"Etu_Sponsor"})})
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Etude
{
...
}
```

I already checked API Platform's documentation in order to configure a custom filter, I checked other sources on the internet but I found nothing looking like my case even on Stack Overflow.
I also cleared my cache, checked my Symphony logs but no issues have been showing.
Ib also tried to misconfigure my filter to check if it's even detected and it showed me an error, which makes me think that my filter is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your using api platform version below 2.7.

Your custom filter need to extend `AbstractContextAwareFilter`, [see api platform custom filter docs (version 2.5)](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.5/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters) :

> Custom filters can be written by implementing the ApiPlatform\Core\Api\FilterInterface interface

For your entity you have to do this (don't forget to add the use NotCaracteristiqueFilter) :

```
use App\Filter\NotCaracteristiqueFilter;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  ...
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(NotCaracteristiqueFilter::class)
 */
class Etude
{
    // ...
}
```

You don't need to add `filters={NotCaracteristiqueFilter::class}` in your `@ApiResource`, and because of autowiring you don't need to update `services.yaml`. Also be aware that you have a duplicate `collectionOperations` key in `@ApiResource`.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to specify my API Platform version, I'm using V2.7

Comment: Okay so you have to look at the use statements carefully, both in your entity and your filter class. For example `use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine` became `use ApiPlatform\Doctrine` in version 2.7 and `use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource` became `use ApiPlatform\ Metadata\ApiResource`